# Compare pixels moved but similar images using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

When comparing two images, both of the images are the same, except that in one of the images the text is moved by a couple of pixels. Please take a look at the below URL. It is a GIF that shows the difference of both the similar images.

https://giphy.com/gifs/9x50JjoLSPZ7lKRebk

My team initially used compare command which doesn't address this issue. Need suggestions please?

Comment: The numbers aren't *moved* by a couple of pixels - they are a different size.

Comment: True, but I feel along with a different size, they are even moved by a couple of pixels because the icons above the graph keep moving up and down

Comment: What is it that you need to have done? You have not explained what you want. Do you want that frames corrected or do you only want to measure the image differences? What have you tried? What version of Imagemagick and what platform? I note from `identify giphy.gif` that the first frame is 1 pixel taller than the second frame. You could try chopping it off by 1 pixel at either the top or bottom to see if that helps.

Comment: I want to compare these images and ignore those pixel differences and size difference when it returns the result. I am using 'compare' command, which is pretty strict in comparisons, so it returns saying both are not the same.

Comment: What do you mean by ignore? If these issue were somehow to be ignored, then the result from compare would say they were exactly identical. Your request does not make sense. Please clarify further. How were the two frames created such that they appear different?

Comment: I note from identify giphy.gif that the first frame is 1 pixel taller than the second frame. You could try chopping it off by 1 pixel at either the top or bottom to see if that helps. As Mark Setchell has said, the fonts are not the same.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Added few more details. 

ImageMagic version: 6.7.6-0
Platform: Windows

I am running this using a selenium automation test, so I look for the value returned by the compare command to decide if the test passed or failed. I want to compare the bar chart generated by my automation test to a baseline chart image to see if the data is any different than the baseline image. I am looking for  ways to handle this pixel variations and font size differences.

Comment: Still unsure what you need done. The frames are different due to size difference and due to font differences. So they are not identical. You could try using `compare -metric phase ...`, but your Imagemagick version is ancient (about 250 versions old). You would likely need to upgrade. See http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=24906

Comment: So if the `800` on left gets a little larger, or smaller, or moves a bit, or changes font, the images should be declared identical, but if it changes to `900` they are deemed to differ? What if it changes to slightly different colour?

Comment: So if the 800 on left gets a little larger, or smaller, or moves a bit, or changes font, the images should be declared identical - True

if it changes to 900 they are deemed to differ - Yes

What if it changes to slightly different colour? - Color differences should cause the comparison to fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove all the text in Imagemagick and just compare the bars by thresholding the Saturation/Chroma channel and then doing the compare. The text is gray, so it has little if any saturation. The bars are cyan, so they are colored and have a medium to high saturation.

```
convert giphy.gif -colorspace HCL -channel g -separate +channel -threshold 5% +write tmp.gif miff:- | compare -metric rmse - null: 
3164.96 (0.0482942)
```

So this is 4.8% different.

I save tmp.gif, which you do not need, only to show the result of the processing before the compare.

[image]

If your version of Imagemagick is too old and you do not have -colorspace HCL, then try HSL or HSB. C and S are similar and measure saturation/chroma.

Comment: I think OP is grabbing the screen of some application she is developing and trying to use **ImageMagick** as part of an automated test process that checks the application consistently produces the correct screens. I guess the content must be correct but the presentation should be allowed to vary slightly. There is a related, but deleted, question which I don't think you can see till 20,000 points.

Comment: In my selenium test, I use **ImageMagick** only at the point where I create a chart and I have to compare this chart to a reference chart image that I have saved on my local.   
'I guess the content must be correct but the presentation should be allowed to vary slightly' - True

Comment: You can do the same thing I did above with two different images rather than two frames of a gif animation. The problem you are having stems from having one image created by different processing than the other. So it is not likely you will get them to match positionally perfectly. My technique at least removes that textual differences in fonts and positioning of text. Once the text is removed, if there is only a slight positioning of the two same sized images, you can use other methods to compare them. Or pad one of processed images with black and use compare with -subimage-search.